# GWT - Styles not picked up from the css file correctly

Tags: gwt

I am facing this wierd situation with GWT where styles are not picked up from the CSS file correctly.

I am trying to style a text area. I know that it picks up default styles from either clean.css or standard.css.

But i have removed the inherit line from the application.gwt.xml file and copied all those styles into my own custom stylesheet file - application.css

And i am trying to add this style name ("close" see below) to my textarea like this

```
       TextArea ta = new TextArea();
       ta.addStylename("close");
```

But it is not picking up the class name "close" at all. I have the default styles for text area copied into application.css from standard.css. 
I checked the page using firebug and chrome's inspect element, i could see see the element as this -

```
   <textarea class="gwt-TextArea close"></textarea>
```

I see styles only being picked up from class - gwt-TextArea.

could someone help me out here.

```
//// styles in application.css
          .close  {
       font-size:150%;
          }

          .gwt-TextArea {
            border: 1px solid #d9dbdb;
             background: #ffffff;
             color: #8e8e8e;
             font: Arial, sans-serif;
              overflow: auto;
           }
```

Comment: How do you include application.css ?

Comment: Yes .... the other style(.gwt-TextArea) is picked up but not the style "close". both r in same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping out. But I figured out that my css file had a syntax error somewhere in the middle of the file and hence all the styles written below that error were not picked up. 
That was a tough thing .. because i was all the time wondering if I was doing anything wrong in the way I am handling styling through GWT.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the setStyleName(), which will add a style name to the object.
After doing that you can use .close { } like you are using now.

What addStyleName does is it creates another style wich is dependent on the main style name in this case .gwt-TextArea close{ } (I'm not 100% sure of this, the documentation isn't very clear).

Anyways it's a good habit to use setStyleName() and setStylePrimaryName().

btw. if you like the answer please click on the button on the left side of the post so it's marked as answered :)

Comment: Thanks for answer ... I actually was wondering whats the difference between setStylename and addStylename

Answer (score 0):

In GWT, styles are obfuscated by default, so you can reuse style names across your different widgets.

You have to use a special CSS class mapping to use styles programmatically : the CssResource.

```
interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
  String myCssClass();
}

class MyResources extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("my.css")
  MyCssResource css();

  @Source("some.png")
  ImageResource imageAccessor();

  @Source("some.png")
  @ImageOptions(repeatStyle=RepeatStyle.Horizontal)
  ImageResource repeatingImage();
}
```

You then use this clientbundle via GWT deferred binding.

See here for more information :
http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. I could try this for method in future